# Можно ли определить, переходил ли пользователь по ссылке на своем сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

В гугле есть такая тема что после перехода по ссылке на какой то ресурс, в будущем этот ресурс в гугле подсвечивается не синим цветом, а фиолетовым.
Сегодня я занимался версткой, и заметил такую тему и на обычных сайтах. Есть ли способ как то определить на стороне джава скрипта этот момент, ну и можно ли на своем сайте кастомизировать просмотренную ссылку за счет css?

Comment: Кастомизировать через css - да, на JS узнать - нет.

Comment: Это не в гугле такая тема, это стандартная фича любого браузера

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете кастомизировать через css, для этого нужно использовать `:visited`. [Документация](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp).

```css
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Stack<a>
<a href="https://google.com/">Google<a>
<a href="https://example.com/">Example<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для теории—в реальности у самой ссылки (anchor элемента) нет состояния "просмотренная". Используемый браузер пометит ссылку "просмотренном" стилем если она направляет на веб-адрес который уже есть в истории браузера.

Исходя из этого, один из способов сделать ссылку "просмотренной" со стороны JS—это добавить её в историю браузера при помощи history API (которого нет в версиях хтмл раньше 5-и).

1. Сохранить данный веб-адрес в переменной.

```js
let currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

2. Используя метод `replaceState` от объекта `history`, добавить веб-адрес ссылки, которую желаете пометить "просмотренном" стилем, в историю браузера.

```js
window.history.replaceState({}, '', '<просмотренный веб-адрес>');
```

3. Использовать метод `replaceState` ещё раз, чтобы исправить веб-адрес видимый в адресной строке браузера после первого вызова метода `replaceState` на действительный веб-адрес просматриваемой страницы (в общем веб-адрес в переменной `currentUrl`).

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', currentUrl);
```

Стоит подметить что этот способ только работает в рамках [правила ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). В двух словах—веб-адрес в ссылке, которую вы хотите пометить "просмотренном" стилем, может только перенаправлять на хост (с тем же протоколом) на котором будет проводиться эта операция.

Answer (score 0):

Этот пример показывает, как с помощью JS без использования истории можно определить, переходил ли пользователь по ссылке на сайте и кастомизировать их. Для этого добавляем на страницу такой код:

```js
let visitedColor = 'red'; // цвет ссылок, по которым был переход
let all_a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
let v = localStorage.getItem('visited');
for(var i = 0; i < all_a.length; i ++){
    all_a[i].id = i;
    all_a[i].onclick = function(){
        this.style.color = visitedColor;
        localStorage.setItem('visited', v + (v == '' ? '' : ',') + this.id);
    }
}
if(v){
    let allVisited = v.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < allVisited.length; i ++){
        all_a[allVisited[i]].style.color = visitedColor;
    }
}
```

Ссылки, по которым был сделан переход, окрашиваются в цвет, заданный в первой строке.